# Recursively flatten nested list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, generator

I am playing around a bit with generators in Python, and am trying to make use of a *simple recursive scheme to implement a flatten-function*. That is, a function that takes as input a list that may contain sublists, and outputs a iterable objects that iterates only over the atomic elements of the input.

So, `print(list(flatten([1,2,3,[4,5,6]])))` should return something containing `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

My attempt is as follows:

```
def flatten(toflatten):
    try:
        for element in toflatten:
            flatten(element)
    except TypeError:
        yield toflatten
```

So, it should *check whether its argument is an iterable object*. If this is the case, also *recurse over this object*. Else, *yield it as an atomic element*.

This does not work and `flatten([1,2,3,[4,5,6]])` merely returns an empty list.

Why is this the case? And in particular; why is it not even performing the recursive function calls on this input? (I am using Python 3.5)

Comment: First of all, what do you expect `flatten(element)` to do? This line does not return/yield anything and does not mutate any data structure, so it's pointless.

Comment: I know this will not be helpful if your end goal is to learn recursion but try `sum(yourlist,[])` this will flatten your list. I would recommend returning a your list at the end.

Comment: @TomosWilliams no, you can't concat ints and lists.

Comment: You should put the `try-except` _inside_ the loop.

Comment: @timgeb ahh you're right! that's just the trick I tend to use when flattening lists

Comment: Id expect it to either yield its atomic values or apply flatten on its sublists. I don't really get why it does not 'yield' the atomic values of, say, [1,2,3]. (say we doing something like: for x in flatten([1,2,3]): print(x)    )

Comment: @ChuckSchuldiner consider the function `foo(x): return 2*x`. Why would you expect a line  that just contained `foo(x)` to be useful? The input parameter is not mutated and you don't use the result.

Comment: @timgeb Ah, I see what you mean now! Thanks (to all) for your comments. I was assuming that the yield-statements in the recursive function-call would transfer to the lower recursion level. So apparently this is not the case. Is there an elegant way of fixing this?

Comment: By the way, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists) is the canonical "flatten nested lists" question. I didn't close as a duplicate because this one seems more about why the specific code does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, you're trying to flatten a list. You're on the right track but you've made a couple of mistakes. Here they are.

1. Move your `try-except` *inside* the loop. With your code, if a `TypeError` is raised for one element, then the loop stops running. You don't want that happening.
2. In the try, you yield nothing. Only making a function call. You should be returning something from there as well. I'd recommend `yield from` if you have python3.3+.
3. Finally, in the `except`, you need to `yield element`, not `toflatten`. Don't yield the entire list.

```
def flatten(toflatten):    
   for element in toflatten:
       try:
           yield from flatten(element)
       except TypeError:
           yield element
```

This gives,

```
>>> list(flatten([1,2,3,[4,5,6]]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

You've used the EAFP (Easier to Ask Forgiveness, than Permission), which is nice. That's one way to do it (my favourite, actually), but there's a drawback: **This crashes on strings.**

---

There's another approach: LYBL (Look Before You Leap). It consists of being more cautious, using `if` statements so errors are not raised.

```
def flatten(toflatten):    
   for element in toflatten:
       if isinstance(element, list):
           yield from flatten(element)
       else:
           yield element
```

Which works the same as before, and gives,

```
>>> list(flatten([1,2,3,[4,5,6]]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

However, this is advantageous, in the fact that the `yield from` generator delegation is only invoked upon sub-lists. Did I mention it also works with string elements?

```
>>> list(flatten([1,2,3,[4,5,'abc']]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'abc']
```

---

Note that in either case, the caveat of infinite recursion, if you have recursively defined lists. For example, `flatten` will crash with this sort of input.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
x.append(x)

flatten(x)
```

You'll end up getting a runtime error:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: You may also want to consider "unwanted" iterables such as strings and if you are particularly picky the possibility of a recursive `toflatten` iterable. (e.g. `toflatten = []; toflatten = [toflatten]`)

Comment: @timgeb Mentioned that EAFP fails with strings, and both fail with recursive lists. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Awesome, all problems solved, thanks a lot! (I was not yet familiar with the yield-from statement, this is exactly what I was looking for)

Comment: Ah, excuse me. New Python user + new Stack overflow user ;)

Comment: Look you, before leaping.